# Why is the C++ std::exception::what member const?

Tags: c++, exception, gcc, constants

I'm curious as to why the `std::exception::what` member function is `const`?

```
class exception 
{
public:
  exception() throw() { }
  virtual ~exception() throw();

  /** Returns a C-style character string describing the general cause
   *  of the current error.  */
  virtual const char* what() const throw();
};
```

Comment: Why would it need to be non-const?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Calling the `what()` member function should not modify the observable state of the `exception` object.

Typically, exceptions are caught by const reference.  For example,

```
try {
    // ...
}
catch (const std::exception& ex) {
    std::cout << ex.what();
}
```

If the `what()` member function was not const-qualified, this pattern wouldn't work because you wouldn't be able to call it from within the catch block.

If you don't want to generate the string to be returned from `what()` until it is called, you can materialize the string into a mutable member variable.

Comment: You sir, are precognizant of my next question.

Comment: actually in most of the code I've seen exception are caught by reference, even though you cannot do anything to modify them.. old habit I guess.

Answer (score 4):

Because it doesn't mutate the `Exception` instance.

In general, all functions that do not mutate their class instance should be declared `const`, so that they can be called on `const`-qualified variables.

Answer (score 3):

Flip the question.  Why would it not be const?

If it was "char *what() const", you could modify the internal char array that what() is returning a pointer to.  It'd be astoundingly stupid for exception() to allow arbitrary code to manipulate its internal buffers in that way, so what() returns a const char *, instead of a char *.

And if it was "const char *what()", without the const qualifier, it would indicate that calling what() would modify the internal state of the exception.  Which it doesn't, and which you'd not expect it to do.

So we have what we have, "const char *what() const".  A const function returning a pointer to a const array.  And the result is that you can call it on a const reference.  Which exceptions generally are.

After all, you don't usually change exceptions, you construct them, throw them, and then have the handling code manipulate them without changing them.  So their member functions should be const.

Answer (score 2):

The reasoning probably came from a desire to uphold stability.  For example, an exception could be thrown if a process runs out of memory.  If that is the case, it would be counter productive to modify "What" so that it might need more space.  If the programmer attempted that, under those circumstances, it would immediately abort the whole program.  Probably not what you intended.

Likewise, it is not appropriate for the What to use extra space from the stack - since that is precisely what is uwinding during a thrown exception.

That said, the boost library has a boost::exception that *does* allow you to add material to it as the exception propogates upward.  Caveat Emptor.

Comment: That's an interesting addition, and semi-answers why what returns a pointer and not a string.